# Transform and reshape a Data Frame from wide to long with additional column

Tags: dataframe, indexing, pivot, melt

I have a data frame that I want to transform from wide into a long format. But I do not want to use all columns.
In detail, I want to melt the following data frame

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'year': [2014, 2018,2020,2017], 
        'model':[12, 14,21,8],
        'amount': [100, 120,80,210],
        'quality': ["low", "high","medium","high"]
       }

# pass column names in the columns parameter 
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
print(df)
```

into this data frame:

```
data2 = {'year': [2014, 2014, 2018, 2018, 2020, 2020, 2017, 2017], 
        'variable': ["model", "amount", "model", "amount", "model", "amount", "model", "amount"],
        'value':[12, 100, 14, 120, 21, 80, 8, 210],
        'quality': ["low", "low", "high", "high", "medium", "medium", "high", "high"]
       }

# pass column names in the columns parameter 
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data2)
print(df2)
```

I tried pd.melt() with different combinations of the input parameters, and it works somehow if I do not take the *quality* colum into consideration. But according to the result, I can not skip the *quality* column. Furthermore, I tried df.pivot(), df.pivot_table(), and pd.wide_to_long(). All in several combinations. But somehow, I do not get the desired result. Maybe pushing the columns *year* and *quality* into the data frame index would help, before performing any pd.melt() operations?

Thank you very much for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'year': [2014, 2018,2020,2017],
        'model':[12, 14,21,8],
        'amount': [100, 120,80,210],
        'quality': ["low", "high","medium","high"]
       }

# pass column names in the columns parameter
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
print(df)

data2 = {'year': [2014, 2014, 2018, 2018, 2020, 2020, 2017, 2017],
        'variable': ["model", "amount", "model", "amount", "model", "amount", "model", "amount"],
        'value':[12, 100, 14, 120, 21, 80, 8, 210],
        'quality': ["low", "low", "high", "high", "medium", "medium", "high", "high"]
       }

# pass column names in the columns parameter
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data2)
print(df2)

df3 = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['year', 'quality'], var_name='variable', value_name='value')
df3 = df3[['year', 'variable', 'value', 'quality']]
df3.sort_values('year', inplace=True)

print(df3)
```

Output (for df3):

```
   year variable  value quality
0  2014    model     12     low
4  2014   amount    100     low
3  2017    model      8    high
7  2017   amount    210    high
1  2018    model     14    high
5  2018   amount    120    high
2  2020    model     21  medium
6  2020   amount     80  medium
```